# How to make SQL query to retrieve all last transactions for every year from a transaction table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have a table where I record all transactions with transaction date and other details . I need an sql statement to retrieve all the last transactions for every year, specially the last date of transaction for every year. I'm using MSSQL 2014
Ex, If my records starts from 01/01/2000, I need to get all the last date of transaction from 01/01/2000 to present.

Example expected result:

```
TransactionDate
--------------------
12/31/2000
12/29/2001
12/30/2002
12/31/2003
.
.
.
12/30/2021
```

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Show us sample data _and_ the (matching) expected result - to make things clearer. Simplify if possible. I.e. [mcve].

Comment: You need to TAG your RDBMS

Comment: sorry forgot to put my rdbms, I'm using MSSQL 2014

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try breaking your TransactionDate into a year using DATEPART. Once you have that, you can select max TransactionDate and group by year, to get the last transaction of each year

That would look like this…

```
SELECT LastTransactionDateOfYear
FROM (
    SELECT DATEPART(year,TransactionDate),
        MAX(TransactionDate) LastTransactionDateOfYear
    FROM <yourtable>
    GROUP BY DATEPART(year,TransactionDate)
)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).